Calculating the total of an invoice
I am curious, how the total value of an invoice is calculated. Let's say that we have the following invoice:

Now, there are 2 ways to do this, that I can imagine.
First method: You add the tax to the unit price, round it up to cents, and then multiply per quantity
1. $10 * 1,1396 = 11.396 
2. Rounds up to a unit price of $11.40
3. $11.40 * 2 = $22.80

Second method You multiply unit price per quantity, then apply tax, and then round up to cents
1. $10 * 2 = $20
2. $20 * 1.1396 = 22.792
3. Rounds down to $22.79

What is the way that it is actually done, when calculating invoice totals?

This will depend on the location. The national/state/local government tells the merchant how to calculate it.

Does this answer your question? Sales tax calculation algorithm

Third method - calculate the tax as a percentage, round it up, and add it to the subtotal.

Whichever way you do it, I suggest you remit every penny that is shown on the invoice as  'tax'.

It depends on the jurisdiction. Using the state of Washington in the United States as an example.
RCW 82.08.054 provides:

Sellers shall compute the tax due under this chapter and chapters 82.12 and 82.14 RCW by carrying the computation to the third decimal place and rounding to a whole cent using a method that rounds up to the next cent whenever the third decimal place is greater than four. Sellers may elect to compute the tax due on a transaction on an item or an invoice basis. This rounding rule shall be applied to the aggregated state and local taxes.

This means, applying the rounding method of WA, the retailer in the example could compute the sales tax due in either of the following two ways.

Per item-basis.

Each item has tax due: $10 * 13.96% = $1.396
Adding them together: $1.396 + $1.396 = $2.792
Rounding down: $2.79


Transaction basis:

Total invoice before tax: $10 + $10 = $20
Total tax due: $20 * 13.96% = $2.792
Rounding down: $2.79



In Method 1, I assumed that two of the same kind of item can be seen as two items for the purpose of RCW 82.08.054. I don't know if this is true.
There is also a survey in 2001 (page 5) on how each US state rounds their sales tax.
